# How to disable highlighting of active tabs in sidebar in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sidebar

Sublime Text 3 automatically highlights the currently active tab (file) in the sidebar. So when I switch between tabs, the highlighted file in the sidebar continuously changes. I know this is actually a feature that many developers like, but that's not the behavior I want. When I click on a file in the sidebar, I'd like to have it remain highlighted, regardless of the active tab. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Under Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings, set `"inactive_sheet_dimming"` to `"false"`.

[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTYVG.png)

Comment: By "highlighting", I was possibly not clear enough. I actually meant "automatically making the current file _selected_ in the sidebar". I no longer use Sublime Text but I guess `inactive_sheet_dimming` is something related to styling.